# Confused about data ingestion hadoop

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hdfs, ethernet

This may be a simple question but it was conceptual rather than maybe a clear answer that google could provide. But My current understanding is that in order to "ingest" data into the hadoop cluster, you first have to have the data on Master pc or cluster unit. This contradicts with the fact that *I know* you can use hadoop as a method for decentralized data collection, where if each unit has sensors you can collect data on the device and ingest it that way.

Suppose I had a Raspberry pi (or any other peripheral Ethernet device), and I wanted to add data to the Hadoop distributed processing/database. *Would I need to make this ethernet device an entire node on the cluster* ( with its own HDFS contribution, etc.) in order for the device to simply input data to the Hadoop cluster, so that it is accessible from any node? If I don't need to do that, then what what steps do I need to take to accomplish this?

Again sorry if this is too conceptual for this site but I just want to make sure I am understanding before I shrink my scope and zoom in to start coding to make sure I am working on the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, your ethernet device (Raspberry Pi) does not have to been part of the Hadoop cluster. It can upload data to HDFS remotely (e.g. [like this](http://paulscott.co.za/blog/uploading-files-through-java-api-to-hdfs-the-easy-way/)), or to any other datastore that Hadoop can read from.

For example: the Pi could upload data to an Amazon S3 bucket, after which you could start a Hadoop (e.g. on EMR) cluster, that uses S3 as input.

Comment: Would the node on the cluster that reads the data from the S3 bucket to ingest it need to be the master pc or could it be any node? Thanks.

Comment: Hadoop is a distributed system, so each node in the cluster will read it's own portion of the data. Otherwise the master node would quickly become a bottleneck.

Comment: Of course, all right, any more questions it just sounds like I need to actually do it.

Comment: If the answer was useful, then please upvote/mark as answered :)